# Get URL from mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I did some google searching and was unable to get clear answer.

Is it possible to get the current URL from a mobile browser to be used by an app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No.  This isn't possible because 1)the browser is a separate app, there's no way to even know which app is a browser and 2)that would be completely unacceptable for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. Altenative you can use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your application and create a custom `WebViewClient` where you can override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method to catch additional user URL loading requeests